# SQL- how to UpdateMain table if the values are existing from 2 different table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reference, inner-join, multiple-tables

I've been trying to figure it out on how to create a SQL query to update the main table if the values are existing from 2 different table?

example:

```
Table1 (Main)
Employee Number
Name
First Name
Document Name
Filename
Original fileName
DL_Status

Table 2 (list table)
Employee Number
Document Name
Original Filename

Table 3(DIR list)
Original fileName
created
extension file name
```

output:
the DL_Status should be marked as "Completed" and Original fileName will be populated from table2 entries only if the original filename exist from Table 3?

Comment: Please show some data which explains your logic.  Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: Maybe also consider getting rid of this level of data redundancy

Comment: We see two question marks, but what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably

```
UPDATE m
SET [DL_Status] ='Completed', 
    [Original fileName] = f.[Original fileName]
FROM [Main] m
JOIN [list table] l ON l.[Employee Number] = m.[Employee Number] AND l.[Document Name] = m.[Document Name]
JOIN [DIR list] f ON l.[Original fileName] = f.[Original fileName]
-- optionally
WHERE m.[DL_Status] <> 'Completed' OR m.[Original fileName] <> f.[Original fileName]
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can apply join on Table2 and table3 then write a script to update the data to the main table 
Note: If the data is mentioned clearly the answer will be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
update table1 
set dl_status = a.dl_status,
Original_Filename =a.Original_Filename  
from
(select t2.Employee Number, 'Completed' as dl_status,t2.Original_Filename  
from table2  t2,table3  t3
where t2.Original_Filename= t3.Original_Filename) a
where a.Employee Number = table1.Employee Number
```